# java UDP file transfer for multi client, can't bind same address

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, udp, serversocket

My project is a UDP file transfer.

The flow is that :

1. server receives a client request
2. server send file bytes to a client via UDP packet
3. loop 1-2 when new client connect (Thread)

Do I need to create one socket for one client?

When I test in my localhost and create more than one socket, it raises an exception (address is already in use).

How do I implement that app? Any idea ? or my concept is not correct?

Comment: UDP data transfer is not recommended unless you're transferring the file on an internal network, or you implement your own acknowledgement mechanism :) Internet has all sorts of problems like packet loss, reordering.

Comment: No, you create one server-side socket which handles all incoming udp requests. UDP has no "connections". There's just individual packets that can come in from anywhere.

Comment: @Chris: If reordering was a problem, then you'd be using TCP anyways. udp is a perfectly valid acceptable protocol in many usage cases.

Comment: @MarcB Reordering *is* a problem, and so is duplication, and packet dropping. UDP is appropriate in cases where that doesn't matter, e.g. audio or video, but certainly not for file transfer, unless you superimpose something like TFTP.

Answer (score 0):

Only one socket at a time can bind to any given UDP port.

It sounds like you may have more than one thread calling bind(), which would cause all but the first one to return the "already in use" error.  You only need to call bind() once at the beginning, before you spawn your worker threads.

If you need multiple threads to handle incoming messages, you should have a single dispatcher thread listen on the socket and send messages to the worker threads.

If you need multiple threads to send outgoing messages, they can all use the same descriptor.

If you need multiple processes to perform this function, they will need to use separate port numbers.